# How to handle const values in a map with an underlying sorted vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, vector, dictionary

I am creating a map that has it's underlying implementation as a sorted vector. It will likely end up being very similar to the [Boost flat map](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/move/boost/container/flat_map.hpp). The idea is to compromise slower inserts and deletes for faster access by having all the pairs in the map stored in contiguous memory. It is also designed to be a drop in replacement for map, having the exact same interface. There will be some issues with iterator invalidation that are different from the contract of map, but I am prepared to deal with those. A simple interpretation of the problem I am facing is this (non-compiling) piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    pair<const int, int> constPair1(a,b);
    b=30;
    const int c = 40;
    pair<const int, int> constPair2(c,b);
    vector<pair<const int, int>> vec{constPair1,constPair2};
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

The issue I am coming up against is how to deal with `const`. The above code will not compile because sort is not allowed to move around the `const` pairs. The Boost flat map appears to just ignore the problem and drop the `const` qualifier, however, I want a drop in replacement so this isn't an option. How can I maintain the same interface but still allow the underlying sorted interface? If at all possible I would like to avoid `const_cast`.

Comment: Your example acts more like a `std::multimap` as there is one same key mapped to two different values.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it to be more clear

Comment: Still the same as e.g. `your_map.find(10)` will return multiple elements. A `std::map` kan keep multiple *keys* to the same value though.

Comment: Right again, I forgot to change the value. Although its worth noting that whether I want a map or a multi map, the solution I'm looking for is still the same.

Comment: Why do you have two questions on what is basically the same subject? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663233/how-to-sort-a-vector-containing-const-values

Comment: My first question (this one) is meant to be a broader question about how to solve the problem of const. The other one is meant to be more specific about sorting a vector of const if I choose to stick with that method.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `const` semantic is very rough and working with for example a non-const array of const objects or a const array of non-const objects just doesn't fit this schema.

A possible workaround would be to just keep the data in a non-const array and use pointer cast tricks to provide the interface. In other words when you are passed a `pair<const int, int> p` just use `pair<int, int>& ncp(*((pair<int, int>*)&p));` instead. When returning objects to the users you can do the same.

Formally IIRC this is not guaranteed to work, but in implementations I know is ok and the optimizer should be smart enough to generate no code for this change of point of view. One problem could be strict aliasing assumption optimization (that btw creates problems to a lot of low level code), and in that case may be using a union can solve the issue (still remaining of course non correct for the standard).

### EDIT

Actually thinking a bit more about it seems to me that such a "map" would have more problems that just iterator invalidation. For example a pattern that I use (and I bet others use also) relies on the fact that iterator may be invalidated, but the value themselves are never moved around... for example after doing

```
MyClass& foo() {
   ...
   return my_map[key];
}
```

I can be sure that the returned reference will remain valid even if other elements are added or removed from the map. Note that no iterator is used.

Keeping the elements in a vector and moving them around on element insertion (or at first access after an insertion) is going to break this use too.

Comment: If you make those `static_cast<>`s, and drop the type punning the advice would start to match the explanation (`std::pair<const X, Y>` is already assignable to `std::pair<X, Y>` and vice versa (and a number of other implicit conversions, IIRC))

Comment: @sehe: why should you be able to assign a `std::pair<const X, Y>`?

Comment: In that direction only implicit construction applies,  obviously. Also that seems to ignore the bigger point I was making?