# How to sort a vector containing const values

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector set up like this and I want to sort it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a =10;
    int b = 20;
    pair<const int, int> constPair1(a,b);
    b=30;
    pair<const int, int> constPair2(a,b);
    vector<pair<const int, int>> vec{constPair1,constPair2};
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the sort above will not compile because of the `const` values. Is there any way I can sort this vector? Or am I stuck creating a new vector and copying values over?

Comment: why do you have a vector of `const` variables? vector is a dynamic container by nature, isn't it?

Comment: It will be the underlying implementation of a container that has to accept `const` values.

Comment: Can you use std::map? The value_type is std::pair<const Key, T> and is sorted by default. It would be trivial to have std::map<const int, int>.

Comment: @DanShield I don't think a map will work. 23.2.4.7 says that the type requirements for containers apply to key and value type of a map, and a const value is not assignable or movable.

Comment: @DanShield This is actually being used as the underlying implementation for the specialization of a map, so using a std::map would not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to utilize `const_cast`, `override=`, and `swap` to make sorting work:

```
template <class KEY, class VALUE>
class Wrapper {
    std::pair<const KEY, VALUE> d_data;

  public:
    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper &rhs) {
        const_cast<KEY&>(d_data.first) = rhs.d_data.first;
        d_data.second = rhs.d_data.second;
    }

    std::pair<const KEY, VALUE>& data() { return d_data; }
    std::pair<const KEY, VALUE> const& data() const { return d_data; }
};

template <class KEY, class VALUE>
void swap(Wrapper<KEY, VALUE>& a, Wrapper<KEY, VALUE>& b) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(const_cast<KEY&>(a.data().first), const_cast<KEY&>(b.data().first));
    swap(a.data().second, b.data().second);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In C++03, elements in a std::vector have to be copy-assignable and copy-constructible in c++. A pair with a const member does not meet that requirement and is thus invalid. The compiler is right to recject it.

In C++11, elements in a std::vector have to be move-assignable and move-constructible. A pair with a const member cannot be moved and will thus result in invalid code.

Comment: Are you entirely sure about that? Because I can make a vector of `unique_ptr` just fine, and they're neither copy assignable or copy constructible. Perhaps you're referring to C++03?

Comment: Copy-assignable and copy-constructible are the requirements in C++03. In C++11, this was changed to move-constructible and move-assignable. std::unique_ptr is a model of these requirements and thus can be put into a vector in C++11. However, a constant is also not movable.

Comment: Interestingly, GCC 4.7 seems happy to have a vector of pairs with const contents, though it won't let you sort them. VS2013 is happy to create and sort a vector of `const int`, but I guess they're a slightly different case.

Comment: @Rook The type requirements of template parameter types are only checked when the code is actually instantiated. As long as you do not use any methods that call the copy- or assignment operator (or the move-equivalents), it will compile. Strictly I would say that the behavior is undefined as it violates the requirement for the class.

Comment: The compiler doesn't actually reject the vector, just the attempt to move things around using sort

Comment: Yes, that is what I answered above to Rook. But strictly, I would argue that the whole program is illegal because it violates std::vector's requirements.

Comment: Ok, well for the sake of argument lets consider an array instead. Then it would have the same properties I care about (contiguous memory and containing `const` values) but it would be legal. Would there be a  solution then?

Comment: The sort function must be able to assign (or move or swap) the elements of the array, otherwise it cannot modify the array. How would that work for const objects? The only solution I can think of would be to introduce a level of indirection, e.g. a vector or array of const* and use a comparator comparing the pointed to objects.